# After installing a new p7 certificate into Intermediate Certification Authority, do I need to grant access to it?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl-certificate, certificate

It doesn't appear to be necessary and I haven't encountered any issues recently, I'm just curious.

The machine is a Win2003 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no permissions on certificates.  Import them into the computer certificate store (not personal which is user profile based) and you're done.

Comment: Thank you. I've always imported them into the Computer/Personal Certificates store and needed to specifically grant access to them.